# Wordpress Shortcode Output

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm developing a plugin to wordpress using **WordPress Plugin Boilerplate**.
Therefore, I need to create a shortcode to show up my data in one page for the user.

Is it correct to concatenate the HTML as below?

```
function custom_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type' => 'type'
        ),
        $atts
    );

    //get all entries (page 1 with 999999 entries per page should do it:)
    $data = Data::get_entries( $atts['type']);

    ob_start();
    ?>

        <div class="row">
            <header><h3>Expenses</h3></header>
            <p>
                <span class="cf-entries-header app-name">Expense Origin</span>
                <span class="cf-entries-header page-name">Expense Value</span>
            </p>

            <?php
                foreach ( (array)$data['entries'] as $entry ) {
                    echo '<p class="cf-entry">’ .
                    ‘<span class="exp-origin">' . $entry['data']['origin'] . '</span>’ .
                    ‘<span class="exp-value">' . $entry['data']['value'] . '</span>’;
                };
            ?>
        </div>
       <?php

        $output = ob_get_clean();
        return $output;
    };

}
add_shortcode( 'cf_app_entries', 'cf_app_entries' );
```

Comment: We liked the idea of `ob_*`, however, it could be much simpler using `.=` as such: https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-build-a-wordpress-shortcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not right way..

You can't echo all content in shortcode..

You need to bind all content (HTML) in one variable and return this variable

**Example**

```
function loginform() {

$html = '<form class="custom_login_form" rel="" method="POST" role="form" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="useremail" type="text" class="form-control input-field" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="twice-box"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-container">
                <input id="userpassword" type="password" class="form-control input-field" name="userpassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="submit_login" class="btn yell-btn submt-btn">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>';

return $html;
}
add_shortcode('login-form', 'loginform');
```

Please check this ShortCode..

If any issue please let me know..

I will be happy to help you..

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Now, I need to find a way to enqueue my stylesheets

Comment: $css_path is path of url css file..

`code`
wp_enqueue_style('your css name', $css_path);
`code`

Make sure that you need to pass different name (in  place of "your css name") for each css file.. 

if you add same for all css. WordPress will add only one css file. Because WordPress distinguish each file by Css name and add Unique files..